# Response time for queries increased badly when doing a duration test and dropping traffic from 20 TPS to 0.01 TPS

Tags: go-gorm

I have a Go App that runs in kubernetes with an Aurora postgress DB, we use Gorm to connect to the DB.I have noticed that if I do say 5 TPS and above, DB response time is very good in the order of 20ms. However if I do like 30 TPS for 1 hr and then I drop the traffic to 0.01 TPS, the response time will be very high in the order of 1 or 2 seconds.

I have taken tcpdump when the system is in trouble and the tcpdump shows fast response time from the DB. In fact the load in the DB is close to 0 and the DB is a big machine and the stats in aurora are good. As I said system can do high traffic and response time is good, it is only at very low traffic that response time is bad.

If I put low very traffic all time (0.01 TPS), system will be OK for 1-3hrs but eventually it will hit the same problem. Please notice that the query that the system does is the same.

Once we hit the problem, is not like 100% of the queries give bad response time. Some percentage will. It is like if 1 connection is bad or something. Below is an example of output showing that some queries go well (6ms) and some very bad (1-2 seconds) and also we see "write: broken pipe" in the log (I changed the logs at some extent to not to give company information):

```
[6.125ms] [rows:0] SELECT DISTINCT "ab_cd" FROM "def" WHERE "xx.yy"."zz" = '13b27c60' AND "sed"."sad" = '668d81c8'
[6.205ms] [rows:0] SELECT DISTINCT "ab_cd" FROM "def" WHERE "xx.yy"."zz" = '13b27c60' AND "sed"."sad" = '668d81c8' 
[6.189ms] [rows:0] SELECT DISTINCT "ab_cd" FROM "def" WHERE "xx.yy"."zz" = '13b27c60' AND "sed"."sad" = '668d81c8' 
2023/10/18 00:40:40 something.go:52 SLOW SQL >= 200ms
[1199.091ms] [rows:0] SELECT DISTINCT "ab_cd" FROM "def" WHERE "xx.yy"."zz" = '13b27c60' AND "sed"."sad" = '668d81c8' 
2023/10/18 00:40:40 something.go:52 SLOW SQL >= 200ms
[1976.256ms] [rows:0] SELECT DISTINCT "ab_cd" FROM "def" WHERE "xx.yy"."zz" = '13b27c60' AND "sed"."sad" = '668d81c8'
{"level":"error","msg":"write tcp 10.32.33.222:12780-\u003e127.0.0.6:46357:  write: broken pipe","time":"2023-10-18T00:59:03.628493Z"}
2023/10/18 00:59:05 something.go:52 SLOW SQL >= 200ms
[1972.147ms] [rows:0] SELECT DISTINCT "ab_cd" FROM "def" WHERE "xx.yy"."zz" = '13b27c60' AND "sed"."sad" = '668d81c8' 
{"level":"error","msg":"write tcp 10.32.33.222:12780-\u003e127.0.0.6:46357:  write: broken pipe","time":"2023-10-18T00:59:05.640271Z"}
2023/10/18 00:59:05 something.go:52 SLOW SQL >= 200ms
[520.439ms] [rows:0] SELECT DISTINCT "ab_cd" FROM "def" WHERE "xx.yy"."zz" = '13b27c60' AND "sed"."sad" = '668d81c8'
[6.216ms] [rows:0] SELECT DISTINCT "ab_cd" FROM "def" WHERE "xx.yy"."zz" = '13b27c60' AND "sed"."sad" = '668d81c8'
[6.163ms] [rows:0] SELECT DISTINCT "ab_cd" FROM "def" WHERE "xx.yy"."zz" = '13b27c60' AND "sed"."sad" = '668d81c8'
[6.089ms] [rows:0] SELECT DISTINCT "ab_cd" FROM "def" WHERE "xx.yy"."zz" = '13b27c60' AND "sed"."sad" = '668d81c8'
```

The only cure for this is to restart the POD hosting the App.

I have played with all sort of values for the following tunables, issue doesn't go away:

DB_CONN_MAX_LIFETIME

DB_MAX_IDLE_CONNS

DB_CONN_MAX_IDLE_TIME

DB_MAX_OPEN_CONNS

Thanks!

Comment: I configured:
  DB_CONN_MAX_LIFETIME: "1800"
  DB_MAX_IDLE_CONNS: "10"
  DB_CONN_MAX_IDLE_TIME: "30"
  DB_MAX_OPEN_CONNS: "50"

Then I put traffic as explained earlier, reproduced the high response time at  0.02 TPS. Then stopped the load, left the system idle for 1 hrs, came back and the system is still showing high latency. 

Any idea why the above settinsg are not respected? If they were, the connection pool after 60 minutes should be in the same state than when I start the pod, isn't?